# Accidentally deleted tor from /usr/sbin

Tags: tor

I deleted tor from /usr/sbin, but after installing tor from web I placed the executable into /usr/sbin. Does it make any issue?
Second question is, before removing from /usr/sbin when I typed `which tor` it given `usr/sbin/tor` , after removing when I entered `which tor`  I gives `/usr/bin/tor`, but tor is showing in /usr/sbin too , why????

Answer (score 0):

See `echo $PATH` as to the why: 1st location found is shown as the location to the executable. It will be something like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

So `sbin` before `bin` in the 2 regular locations (`/usr/local`, and `/usr`)

As long as it can be found in your PATH it will be fine. I doubt it is envoked using a directory.

Comment: After ``` echo $PATH ``` i am getting this ```/home/abinash/Downloads/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin ```.